# onCreateView() not called for second time

Tags: android, view, fragment

I have mainactivity with fragment and my View in this fragment is null when I come back to this activity after being in other activity. Why is onCreateView() not called again when I enter MainActivity and onCreate() is called? I want to make some changes in fragment everytime I come back to this activity, how can I do it?

Fragment:

```
private View v;
private TextView info;
    public MyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sun, container, false);


        return v;
    }
    private void setFields(){
        info= v.findViewById(R.id.infoText); //View is null here when I comeback to MainActivity
    }

    public void calculateWeather(double longitude, double latitude){
      setFields();
    //do sth

    }
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if(intent != null){
            String response = intent.getStringExtra("SETTINGS_BACK");//to detect back to this activity

            if(response != null){
                refreshView();
            }
        }

    private void setViewPager(){
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 2);
    adapter.addFragment(new SunFragment(), "Sun");

    tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    if(viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        Fragment f = adapter.getItem(0);
        sunFragment = (SunFragment)f;
    }
    if(tableLayout != null){
        tableLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    }

   private void refreshView(){
    if(viewPager != null) {
        sunFragment.calculateWeather(lon, lat);
   }
```

PagerAdapter

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int fragmentNumber;
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> fragmentsNameList = new ArrayList<>();


    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int fragmentNumber){
        super(fm);
        this.fragmentNumber = fragmentNumber;
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String name){
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentsNameList.add(name);
    }

    public SunFragment getSunFragment(){
        return (SunFragment)fragmentList.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            return SunFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentsNameList.get(position);
    }
}
```

//edited: added remaining code

Comment: How did you attach fragment to `MainActivity`?

Comment: I just added missing code. So I have PagerViewer Adapter and get this fragment in MainActivity and call calculateWeather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Fragment's view will get destroyed in following cases:

1) activity is is attached to gets killed by system or user.

2) you yourself call detach on it or call a replace for a new fragment on the same parent view id that it's attached to

3) your fragment goes out of the viewpager offscreen page limit. Default is 1 fragment on either side staying alive. When it goes beyond that, the fragments not in the window get destroyed. Similarly as soon as a fragment falls into this window, they'll get created.

Since nothing in your case points to any of the above, makes no sense for the system to create the view again

However you can listen to the changes in onResume as it will definitely get called when the activity gets un paused after coming back from another activity.

Comment: onResume is even called after launching activity for 1st time, but I managed to do what I wanted. Thanks